# Problema com modulos python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Eu estou tentando rodar um condigo simples que é constituído por uma requisição.
So que sempre que tento rodar ele no meu ubuntu 20 ele retorna o seguinte erro

```
  File "autobump.py", line 1, in <module>
  import requests
  ImportError: No module named requests
```

Usando pip list ele retorna que esta instalado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import requests
import time

while 1:
payload = {
    'content': '!d bump'
}

header = {
    'authorization': '*'
}

r = requests.post("", data=payload, headers=header)

print('bumped')
time.sleep(7260)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa confusão é comum quando temos instaladas mais de uma versão do `python` ou utilizamos uma `virtualenv` para empacotar bibliotecas necessárias para determinados projeto. Caso você possua mais de uma versão do `python`, então isso significa que você tem um conjunto diferente de bibliotecas para cada uma dessas versões.

Agora vamos a uma das possíveis causas:

Dependendo da `IDE` que você esteja utilizando, ela pode possuir configurações para indicar qual interpretador (binário da versão do `python`) você deseja utilizar, como é o caso do `pycharm` que eu utilizo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa aba é possível ver os interpretadores que a `IDE` reconheceu por padrão ou eu adicionei. Com isso sugiro você verificar se a `IDE` aponta para o interpretador correto (que possui a biblioteca `requests` e que seja a versão do `python` que você deseja utilizar). Caso não esteja aparecendo o interpretador que você deseja utilizar, então é necessário adicionar pelo botão `add interpreter`.

Eu recomendo também que você passe mais informações com relação ao ambiente que você está utilizando, se está rodando o programa direto por um botão da `IDE`, se você realmente possuí mais de uma versão do `python`, ou se está utilizando `virtualenv`. Se você conseguir passar esse tipo de informação, facilitará para que te ajudemos a resolver o problema.